# Python str.find() overriding Element.find(), how to circumvent?

Tags: python

I am writing some code that uses the `Element.find()` method from Python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` module.  However, I am finding that as soon as I start using `str.replace()`, Python thereafter interprets my calls to `object.find()` as `str.find()` rather than `Element.find()`.

I need my code to grab the text from various `Element` objects from an XML file, and in some cases I need to modify it with `str` methods.  How can I do this without changing how the interpreter interprets `object.find()`?  Here my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
import re
import json

pattern = re.compile('[a-z,0-9,-]+')
c_pattern = re.compile('\[caption[^\]]+\]')
c2_pattern = re.compile('\[/caption\]')

tree = xml.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.iter('item'):
    if item.find('{http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/}post_type').text == 'post':
        t = item.find('{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/}encoded').text
        print item.find
        try:
            t = t.encode('utf-8')

            o_cap = re.findall(c_pattern,t)
            e_cap = re.findall(c2_pattern,t)

            for item in o_cap:
                t = t.replace(item,'') 
            for item in e_cap:
                t = t.replace(item,'')           
        except:
            t = 'None'
        print item.find
        title = item.find('title').text
```

The first `print` statement returns `<bound method Element.find of <Element 'item' at 0x2a7a7d0>>`, while the second returns `<built-in method find of str object at 0x2b56e00>`.

I've tried subclassing `Element`, but I don't know how to make the `Element` nodes in my XML file become objects of the new subclass.  I've also tried simply defining a new method that refers to the `Element.find()` method, but when I tried to use it the interpreter simply told me that an `Element` object didn't have a method by the name of my user-defined one.

Another way I've thought of is some kind of

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element.find() as Element.some_other_name()
```

but that doesn't work (I've tried a bunch of syntactic variations and they don't work either).  Does anyone know what I can/should do to get around this issue?

Comment: Can you post some code that is giving you the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are clobbering the name `item`.  Try switching the variable name in your inner loop to something else, like `poop`.

```
for poop in o_cap:  
    t = t.replace(poop,'') 
for poop in e_cap:
    t = alvin.replace(poop,'')
```

Comment: Oh for crying out loud.  Man that was dumb.  Thanks for catching that; I didn't realize I was just reassigning `item`.

Answer (score 2):

Without any code, I can only guess.

The methods which are called always come from the object you are referring to. If you expect `Element.find()` to run, you'll have to have an `Element` object. Instead, you have a `str` object, coming from `replace()`.

One way to go COULD be to replace the contents of the `Element` with the `replace()` result and only then work on it as if it was the original one.

Comment: Without any context (before the code was provided) this was a very good answer.

Comment: Agreed, this was definitely related to my issue.